# Why does asyncio work in cmd but not in Git Bash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-asyncio, git-bash

When I run a python module with asyncio, it works as intended when executed from cmd, but not when executed from git bash.

The code is intended to print "hello", wait 3 seconds, then print "world". It does this correctly in cmd, but in git bash, it waits three seconds first, and then prints both statements back to back.

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('world')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there something inherent in how git bash treats I/O, that causes this behaviour?

I'm using Python 3.10.2 on Windows 10. Git version 2.24.1.windows.2.

Comment: One shell is probably line buffering and the other is block buffering. Check the buffering settings in both terminals.

Comment: Does the issue persist with the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), like Git for Windows 2.35.1.2?

Comment: Please see also: [How can I flush the output of the print function (unbuffer python output)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function-unbuffer-python-output)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I haven't found a way to do this in git bash, are you sure this is possible? Or is it solely dependent on the code that writes to the terminal? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Mofi's comment, I changed my code to this:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('hello', flush=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('world', flush=True)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This forces the buffer to flush after both prints, sending it to the terminal. It works in Git Bash now.

Details:
From what I now understand, under the hood, python sets the buffering depending on the detected device. From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open, files are "usually line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files". Print uses the default sys.stdout file object to write to.

Running a new module with the following code:
import sys

```
print(f'{sys.stdout.isatty()=}')
```

It prints 'sys.stdout.isatty()=True' in cmd but 'sys.stdout.isatty()=False' in git bash, which explains why stdout chooses to fully buffer in git bash, not print until the code exits, and line buffers in cmd.